Higher spin Clifford gates
We're familiar with Clifford gates for qubits, which have attracted a lot of attention and research effort. Clifford circuits normalize Pauli strings, i.e., under conjugation, Clifford circuits map Pauli strings to other Pauli strings. This enables efficient classical simulations of Clifford circuits.
It's natural to think about Clifford gates for higher-dimensional representations of SU(2). Say, for example, we have a collection of spin-1 degrees of freedom. These still have a notion of Pauli string where each Pauli $X, Y, Z$ now has dimension 3. My questions are

Have the generating sets for normalizers of higher-spin Pauli groups been worked out?
Have these "higher dimensional Clifford circuits" attracted much interest? They'd probably be interesting from the perspective of many-body theorists (my area of specialty) but I haven't heard anything about them.

Any references you could point me towards which address these subjects would be very helpful. Thanks in advance.

Not sure if I get this right. The automorphisms of the generators are still the same, but if you look at a different representation (with higher dimension), then this does not define a unique unitary anymore (not even up to phase), but rather a equivalence class (as "Paulis" are not a basis anymore). Thus, it is highly unclear how efficient classical simulation should work in the context. There are higher-dimensional Cliffords, but they do not come from su(2) representations https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/35297/which-clifford-groups-are-2-designs/35369#35369
